# Postman JSON Schema Validation fails, if an Object.prototype function declared prior to the validation

Tags: postman, jsonschema, postman-pre-request-script

I have a schema validation test in my postman collection, which validates if the response adhere to the schema. This is how I do it.

```js
var schema = 
{
  
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "data": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {....
}

    pm.test("Schema Validation - TC001", function(){

    pm.response.to.have.jsonSchema(schema);
    

});
```

When I execute just this script, it validates the schema of the response successfully.

However, in my postman collection I have declared a global function, prior to the schema validation, using Object.prototype() and I'm calling the function as _.funcABC("a","b","c")

```js
Object.prototype.funcABC = function (var1, var2, var3) {
   console.log("test");
}
```

And, my schema validation fails, when I run the entire collection.

While troubleshooting, I came across  [this](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/8064), which indicates that the Object.prototype could interfere with JSONschema.

Is there a way to overcome this interference of Object.prototype() on JSONschema? So far, I couldn't find a workable solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What stops you from doing this:

```
pm.test('validate schema', function () {
    let temp = Object.prototype.function1
    delete Object.prototype.function1
    pm.expect(ajv.validate(schema_response, response)).to.true;
    Object.prototype.function1 = temp
})
```

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: Just have a look at these also

Comment: That's interesting @PDHide. Thanks. I'll have a look.